# Microsoft SQL 2005: I just created a trigger but it won't show me the code under "Database triggers"?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Once you create a trigger with the `create trigger` code, how do you get it to show up in the "Database Triggers" folder?  I refresh and nothing shows.  I know it's there because I can see two database counts when I update the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to find the trigger undeer the table structure itself.

Expand the table, you will see something like `Columns, Keys, Constraints, Triggers, Indexes, Statistics`. It will be under the Triggers section.